# VBA Download Files from website and save them in local without manual intervention

Tags: vba, savefiledialog

I have a button in a website to download textfile, and Once I click on it, I will get a  save as dialogue box to save the file. I know how to click on button but I need your help in handling the save as dialogue box.. there should not be any manual intervention in this process/

Thanks in advance.

Prasad

Comment: To clarify - whey you say "I click on it", you mean you've written some code to click on the button in some automated fashion? If so, there's probably no way to avoid the dialog box. Perhaps a different approach, like downloading the file directly?

Comment: Yes, I have written some vba code to click on it,, and once I clicked, Save as dialogue box is coming..I have click on SAVE on that Dialogue box.

Answer (score 0):

I stand corrected - some enterprising developers have written some code to automatically fill in the "Save As" dialog box. This is not something I've ever done myself so I can't vouch for how well it works, but you might want to take a look at [this code listing by John_W.](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/507871-download-web-table-multiple-pages.html#post2508224)